# PHP array is null after passing to function

Tags: php, arrays, function, class

So I have a problem I have an array that is passes to setData function
 after that I call getE that suppose to return the array but instead I'm getting Null what am I doing wrong?

```
<?php

class Se {      
    public $data1; 

    public function setData(array $data){
        if (empty($data)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('The name of an employee cannot be empty.');
     }

    $data1 = $data;
        $data1 =  array_values($data1);
        var_dump($data1);   
    }


    public function getE(){ 
        return $data1[0];
    }
}

$tmpaaa= array('3333','222');
$ttt = new Se();
$ttt->setData($tmpaaa);

echo $ttt->getE();
```

So my revised code looks like this now

```
class Se {

    public $data1; 

public function setData(array $data)
{

if (empty($data)) 
{
throw new InvalidArgumentException('The name of an employee cannot be empty.');
 }
     $this->data1 = $data;     

}


    public function getE()
{   
return $this->$data1[0];

}



 };
$tmpaaa= array('3','2');
 $ttt = new Se();
$ttt->setData($tmpaaa);
echo $ttt->getE();
 ?>
```

Comment: Remove the `echo $data1[0]` line from `getE`. This doesn't appear in any of the answers and once again, you've not prefixed the class instance property with `$this->`. I strongly suggest you thoroughly read http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.properties.php

Comment: @Phil The new code it's updated above looks exactly the same as xlordt It doesn't run. but copying his example into new file works perfectly. I can't see the difference

Comment: You have `$this->$data1[0]`. It should be `$this->data1[0]`. Have you read the manual page I added above and in my answer?

Comment: Reading it right now @Phil Thanks for the help Now I understand. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: READING IT NOW?! You should have read it before you even started or at least 1 hour ago when first linked

Comment: I'm new to this all started PHP few days ago. Reading it because I'm still trying to understand everything written in there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to access class instance properties from within the class, you need to prefix the variable name with `$this`. See http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.properties.php

To fix your problem, change this in `setData`

```
$data1 = $data;
$data1 =  array_values($data1);
var_dump($data1);
```

to this

```
$this->data1 = array_values($data);
var_dump($this->data1);
```

and `getE` to

```
public function getE(){ 
    return $this->data1[0];
}
```

#### Update

As it appears the `$data1` property is required in `Se`, I'd set it in the constructor, eg

```
public function __construct(array $data) {
    $this->setData($data);
}
```

and instantiate it with

```
$ttt = new Se($tmpaaa);
echo $ttt->getE();
```

Comment: Same thing still getting `PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: data1 in C:\php\ar_test.php on line 14`

`Notice: Undefined variable: data1 in C:\php\ar_test.php on line 14
NULL
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: data1 in C:\php\ar_test.php on line 20`

`Notice: Undefined variable: data1 in C:\php\ar_test.php on line 20`

Comment: @Harry_J I was just updating my answer to include the fix for `getE` as well

Comment: Now I'm getting `PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: data1 in C:\php\ar_test.php on line 14

Notice: Undefined variable: data1 in C:\php\ar_test.php on line 14
NULL
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: data1 in C:\php\ar_test.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined variable: data1 in C:\php\ar_test.php on line 20
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot access empty property in C:\php\ar_test.php on line 20

Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in C:\php\ar_test.php on line 20`

Comment: @Harry_J What's on line 14 now? Still looks to me like you have `$data1` instead of `$this->data1`

Comment: It was var_dump Now I'm getting `array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "3333"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "222"
}
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: data1 in C:\php\ar_test.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined variable: data1 in C:\php\ar_test.php on line 20
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot access empty property in C:\php\ar_test.php on line 20

Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in C:\php\ar_test.php on line 20`

Comment: As I said below, you prob was not comparing codes correct :) my codes and Phils code should of worked.. although I am not sure about using __construct () in this matter... yet should work perfect.

Comment: @Harry_J Looks like you're not reading these answers properly. You will need to use `return $this->data1[0]` in your `getE` method as shown in **all** the answers on this page

Comment: So I added the code I have right now, and I have return `$this->data[0]` in my `getE` but I still receive same errors Undefined variable

Comment: @Harry_J I've commented on your question instead of here. I really feel like you're not reading any of the information provided

Answer (score 1):

It is also recommended not closing the php tag in a class file, this prevents space issues.

```
<?php
class Se {      

    public $data1; 

    public function setData(array $data)
    {
        if (empty($data)) 
        {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('The name of an employee cannot be empty.');
        }

        $this->data1 = array_values($data);  //you error was here, no need to to assign $data twice so I deleted top line.
    }


    public function getE()
    { 
        return $this->data1[0];

    }
}

$tmpaaa = array('3333','222');
$ttt = new Se();
$ttt->setData($tmpaaa);

echo $ttt->getE();
```

Comment: I edited the code replacing with `$this->data1` and getting the errors I told @Phil in third comment

Comment: Just copy and paste any of these codes posted by me/phil, and compare.